# Installing ackermann vehicle package with Indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the ackermann vehicle package from the main repository  using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle
```

However, I am getting a 404 error

> Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/
> trusty/main
> ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-description
> amd64
> 0.1.3-1trusty-20151201-0505-+0000   404  Not Found Err
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/
> trusty/main
> ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-gazebo
> amd64
> 0.1.3-1trusty-20151201-1323-+0000   404  Not Found Err
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/
> trusty/main
> ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle amd64
> 0.1.3-1trusty-20151201-1326-+0000   404  Not Found E: Failed to fetch
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-description/ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-description_0.1.3-1trusty-20151201-0505-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-gazebo/ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-gazebo_0.1.3-1trusty-20151201-1323-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle/ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle_0.1.3-1trusty-20151201-1326-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

Is this package still maintained in Indigo? or is it obsolete?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228898/installing-ackermann-vehicle-package-with-indigo/) by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your apt-cache is out of date, and it's trying to download a previous version of the package.

Try updating your apt cache before installing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) on 2016-03-13**:
After updating the apt-cache (`apt-get update`) the ackermann-vehicle has disappeared, i.e. now I get after

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle
```

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-13**:
(1/3) I'm not sure what happened, but the `ackermann_*` pkgs came out of [wunderkammer](http://www.wunderkammerlab.com), and some time ago all of it was deleted. The [ROS Index page](http://rosindex.github.io/r/ackermann_vehicle/github-wunderkammer-laboratory-ackermann_vehicle/) shows some info.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-13**:
(2/3) The [github organisation](https://github.com//wunderkammer-laboratory) also seems to have been removed. [here](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/New-Repository-ackermann-vehicle-td4020349.html) is the original announcement of the packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-13**:
(3/3) And apparently [jbpassot/ackermann_vehicle](https://github.com/jbpassot/ackermann_vehicle/network/members) is a fork (which seems like it is the 'top fork' at the moment).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-13**:
It looks like the package was removed by the author: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/4630294aee35d3df3200e58ef1de178fdbe89e1d

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-13**:
Yeah, that's when I noticed it. Does anyone know why?

Btw: here is a (random) fork of [steered_wheel_base_controller](https://github.com/frederikhegger/steered_wheel_base_controller).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-13**:
Hm, from the [rosdistro PR](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/10129):

tfoote wrote:

> Would it be possible to put a copy of these repos in another organization for archival access?

jim-rothrock:

> Sorry, but no, that would defeat the purpose of deleting the repositories.